# GrandNode MVC Administration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I downloaded GrandNode 3.8 with source code and compiled with vs .net 2015. The store is running but the Administration page does not and I get a 404 Error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance....

[online store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWKiX.jpg)

[Administration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsakU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Please open solution in Visual Studio and rebuild project Grand.Admin. It will fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, it did work after recompiling for (no code version) :) Strangely, it did work with code version.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled aspnet framework on iis.... but still i'm getting 404 on http://[grandnodeserver]/admin